# How can I select data from table1 with multiple attributes from table2 in mysql?

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables in mysql. The first one has user data for example, the second one has attributes data.
I want to select each user from table one and get all attributes for him from table two.

e.g.
table 1:

`| userid   | name   |
 | 1        | John   |
 | 2        | Billie |`

table 2:

`| userid   | attribute   |
 | 1        | male        |
 | 1        | taxi driver |
 | 1        | 45 years    |
 | 2        | female      |
 | 2        | clerk       |`

So I want to get my mysql results like this:

`| userid  | name    | attributes                  |
 | 1       | John    | male, taxi driver, 45 years |
 | 2       | Billie  | female, clerk               |`

I absolutely have noch idea, how to get these attributes consolidated (maybe even comma seperated). I also searched here, but found nothing similar.

Can you help please? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can user [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) for that perhaps.

```
SELECT userid, name, GROUP_CONCAT(attribute) as attributes
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.userid = table2.userid
GROUP BY table2.userid
```

See this SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fd365d4/6/0

Answer (score 0):

```
;with SampleDataR as
(
    select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by title, subtitle order by value) rownum
    from test12
)
select distinct title, subtitle,(
    select value 
    + case when s1.rownum = (select MAX(rownum) from SampleDataR where title = s1.title and subtitle = s1.subtitle)
    then '' else ',' end from SampleDataR s1
    where s1.title = s2.title and s1.subtitle = s2.subtitle
    for xml path(''),type).value('(.)[1]','varchar(max)') csvList
    from SampleDataR s2
```

Comment: **Jonathan answer is also correct **
SELECT userid, name, GROUP_CONCAT(attribute) as attributes
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.userid = table2.userid
GROUP BY table2.userid

Comment: And much easier and elegant IMHO than your solution, especially since GROUP_CONCAT has at least been present since MySQL 5.7 I see no need for such an elaborate solution.

Comment: yes i know but we have multiple way to solve one problem once you answered that answers i given an other look to question answer